# Error while opening a file inside a dll

Tags: c++

I am opening a file inside a dll code. I am using `fopen`. The pointer returned by `fopen` is NULL. What am I doing wrong?

```
pFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\bruce\\Desktop\\log.txt","w");
```

I run the code with the debugger. The file gets created but the pointer returned by `fopen` is NULL which throws an exception when I use `fprintf`

Comment: You should post the code you're using. There are a lot of things you might be doing wrong, e.g. does the file really exist? in what mode are you opening it? does the user your process run under have enough privileges to open it?

Comment: Do you have any code? :)  Are you creating / opening an existing file?  Do you have access permissions to the file?...

Comment: Is the current directory of the process what you expect? There is only *one* current directory per process. What is `errno`?

Comment: @Greg: How do I get the errno. I have opened another file inside another dll. Is that creating problems?

Comment: `errno` is a global variable (or, at least, acts like one). `#include <errno.h>` and look at the value after `fopen()` fails.

Comment: Next, use `strerror()` to translate that error number (which is specific to your system) to a human readable string.

Comment: I get a "Result too large" error. What does that mean for fopen?

Comment: @All: I figured out the error. Thanks to Greg. I really appreciate your time. The function where I wrote fopen was getting called multiple time and thus fopen returned NULL. I am now using static variable inside the function to ensure fopen call is made only once. Thank you all!

Comment: Good question, that doesn't seem like an appropriate error return for `fopen()`. Since there is only one `errno`, you have to make sure you capture its value immediately after `fopen()` returns, otherwise it's possible that it might be overwritten by something else in the meantime. Without showing more of your code, it's hard to tell what might be happening.

Comment: I see you've got it sorted now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `fopen()` fails, the error result is stored in the `errno` global variable (be sure to `#include <errno.h>`). The `strerror()` function can convert the `errno` number into a human readable string.